# Changing colours in twoway area graph in Stata

Tags: graph, colors, stata, area

It should be quite "easy" but I can not change colour of both the twoway graph's area. Considering this basic code:

`twoway area yvar1 yvar2 xvar`

How can I set colours of the areas of yvar1 yvar2?

Answer (score 1):

Read the fine help!

```
help twoway area
```

has a link to

```
help area_options
```

with explanation "change look of shaded areas". Find out there about `color()` and related options.